# Excel VBA: Conditions of value first available cell after filter

Tags: vba, excel

*Main question: How can I let the code go one cell down from `Range("A1")` and if that cell is blank (or has no value/text), the msgbox "No values available"  appears and the sub ends? This while trying to remain as flexible as possible (so it wouldn't matter whether I have 18 or 1800 rows)*

Using `Selection.Offset(1,0).select` still only goes directly to cell `Range("A2")`, even though it's been filtered out.

Currently using a range of products with characteristics (opaque, heat resistant, etc) and conditions (yes/no) and applying a filter in order to select the correct range. However, if I'm selecting a lot of characteristics, my sheet shows ALL products again, as the filter doesn't return anything anymore. In order to tackle this problem, I've used the code:

```
Sheets("Data attributes").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Vrow = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Row
If Vrow < 18 Then

Sheets("Data attributes").Range("A2:A" & lrowDA).Copy
Sheets("Result").Activate
Range("A19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
Sheets("Result").Activate
MsgBox "No values available"
End If
```

This however only works for the first 17 lines. If I'm extending the listed products to 350 for example, I should use

```
If vrow < 351, then
```

Etc. , but this is more hardcoding than actually making it as flexible/generic as possible.

Comment: What does your data look like ?And is it possible to do AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).offset... i haven't tested

Comment: Where do you define your variables? If you just want to know where the last row of data is you could use this to get the row number 

`Dim Lrow as Integer 
Dim xlCell as Range 
Dim DataAT As Worksheet
Set xlCell = DataAT.Cells(DataAT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "B") 
Lrow = Mid(xlCell.Address, InStr(2, xlCell.Address, "$", vbTextCompare) + 1) 
Set xlCell = Nothing
Set DataAT = Nothing`

Comment: Will try the specialcells.offset, thanks for the tip with that!